# In which cases can't "whether" be used?

Tags: sentence-construction, usage, american-english

Why can't I use *whether* in this sentence?

> However we have just found a student who is willing to manage the section **whether** the website is still active next year.

Comment: What's it supposed to mean? It doesn't make a lot of sense, but it's impossible to give better answers without knowing what you're talking about (what the student and section are doing and how that relates to the website being active or not).

Comment: Apparently, ["Whether or not" vs. "whether"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3382/whether-or-not-vs-whether) is currently a "Highly active question" over on our sister site ELU.

Answer (score 3):

The original example does not work.

There are a few possibilities, depending on what the OP wants to say.

We can use **whether or not** or **irrespective of whether**:

> However, we have just found a student who is willing to manage the section **whether [or not]** the website is still active next year.

[Whether or not](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whether-or-not) is an idiom and is

> used for saying that it is not important which of two possibilities is true:

> Whether or not you like it, I’m going out tonight.

Another possibility, with a different meaning, is

> However, we have just found a student who is willing to manage the section **provided** the website is still active next year.

Edit

This is a more likely scenario since an inactive website would have nothing much to manage.

The OP must tell us what she wants to say.

Comment: This is the right answer, well summarized. When actually asking a question *("Do you know **if** the shop is open?")* the highlighted term can be replaced by ***whether or not*** - which *in that specific context* can be reduced to just ***whether.*** But when making a *statement* such as OP's example, the reduced version ***whether*** is ungrammatical, and ***if*** and ***whether or not*** have completely different meanings.

Comment: ...but I can't help noticing that my comment currently contains the only 2 (now ***3**!* :) instances of the word ***if*** on this page (which is equivalent to your ***provided / providing***, but arguably less emphatic unless delivered with exaggerated stress).

Comment: You're right.  "...willing to manage the section **if** the website is still active next year" would mean the managing is subject to the stated condition, similar to the use of **provided**.

Comment: ...which I *assume* is the OP's intended sense, since most likely if the website *wasn't* still active next year, there would be nothing for the student to be willing to manage anyway! :)

Comment: Thx, FF.  I have edited my answer.